# Forcefully Unmounting Filesystem

Tags: linux, webdav, fuse, unmount

Okay, here's the deal:

I used FUSE to mount a webdav endpoint as a filesystem. At some point it broke. Now, for the life of me, I cannot unmount it.

Any time I try and interact with it in any way, things just freeze. Listing (`ls`) the directory which contains the mount point freezes my shell up unrecoverably.

I have tried `umount -f` (force), `umount -l` (lazy), `umount -lf` (lazy force) and `fuser -km` (as I've seen recommended elsewhere) all as root... No luck. Any time I run any of these commands they simply hang until I kill (`^C`) them.

There shouldn't be any processes keeping a handle open on this mount. I've tried checking with lsof. That, too, hangs.

I don't care if I have to compile a freaking kernel module to patch this thing out of memory... I need a way to get this gone.

I've spent the last hour searching Google and Stackoverflow. Everything is just a repeat of the same old party line: `umount -f` and `umount -l`. Does anyone know a way to really, truly force a filesystem to unmount?

(Debian 6.0.9, kernel 2.6.32-5)

Comment: Reboot should do it.

Comment: In my experience, Linux won't unmount some filesystems and a reboot is the only practical way to clear the error. This used to happen with NFS a bunch.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another command you can try, though if the things are hanging that badly, this might not help either.

```
fusermount -u /path/to/mountpoint
```

Answer (score 1):

For davfs I find:

```
fusermount -uz /path/to/mountpoint
```

(a lazy unmount) works. If you remount at this point you might get an error about a PID file, so delete it, then retry the mount:

```
rm /var/run/mount.davfs/mountpoint.pid
mount /path/to/mountpoint
```